# Showing swich input value in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii-extensions

I have a switch input that has different values for different defined by value of 3 and when its not 3

I have tried

```
  echo $form->field($model, 'PR_Status_ID')->inline()->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
                        'type' => SwitchInput::RADIO,
                        'items' => [
                            ['label' => 'Complete', 'value' => 3,

                            ],
                            ['label' => 'Incomplete', 'value' =>!3 ],
                        ],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'onText' => 'Yes',
                            'offText' => 'No',
                        ]

                    ])->label(false);;
                    ?>
```

When the value is 3 it shows complete but when not 3 the incomplete label doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

In PHP `!3` evaluates to `false` so your code `['label' => 'Incomplete', 'value' =>!3 ]` is basically saying `['label' => 'Incomplete', 'value' => false ]`

You might want to assign another number for this label.